# php 7.2 ZipArchive class not having setEncryptionName function

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Have upgraded my php version from 5.6 to 7.2 but i dont see new php functions like setEncryptionName for ZipArchive class. i confirm this by echoing get_class_methods('zipArchive'). Do i need to do anything else in order to use the new set of functions the newer php version provides? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZipArchive` class is part of the zip PECL extension for PHP

You will need version 1.14.0 is higher for the `setEncryptionName()` function

See changelog here: https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.14.0

The zip extension depends on libzip >= 1.2.0

NOTE: many Linux distributions ship an older version of libzip. You might be able to find a newer version here: https://libzip.org/packages/
Otherwise you will need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. It works now after upgrading the libzip version