# Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setEncryptionName() on AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP 7.2.17 with zip module enabled

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-ziparchive

I'm running instance on AWS setup with Elastic Beanstalk (it's an Laravel 5.8 application running on a PHP 7.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.9 configuration).

When I SSH into the instance and run a custom artisan command using the ZipArchive module the following error occurs:

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setEncryptionName()
```

If I check the PHP version by calling `php -v` the following shows:

```
PHP 7.2.17 (cli) (built: Apr 15 2019 23:21:08) ( NTS )
```

Since `ZipArchive::setEncryptionName()` should be available from PHP >= 7.2.0 I don't understand why this error occurs.

Also if I check the enabled PHP modules by calling `php -m` the `zip` module is in the list of modules.

Can somebody help me figure out how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

The code lines where the error occurs are:

```
$zip_file = storage_path('app\export-' . Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y-H-i') . '.zip');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
    $this->info("adding files");

    if (!$zip->addFile(storage_path('app/export.xlsx'), 'export.xlsx')) {
        Mail::to('xxx')->send(new ExportFailed('Could not add export.xlsx to zip'));
        $this->error('Could not add export.xlsx to zip');
    } else {
        if(!$zip->setEncryptionName('export.xlsx', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256)){
            Mail::to('xxx')->send(new ExportFailed('Could not set encryption for export.xlsx in zip'));
            $this->error('Could not set encryption for export.xlsx in zip');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code lines where the error occurs (and some lines around this...)

Comment: @Kryptur the code is working fine, the problem lies with the setEncryptionName() method not being available on the server, but I added some of the code.

Comment: You might be using an old version of libzip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 7.2 ZipArchive class not having setEncryptionName function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693230/php-7-2-ziparchive-class-not-having-setencryptionname-function)

Comment: Yes! That's probably it! Somebody knows how to upgrade libzip on an beanstalk instance?

Comment: I just spent the last 2 hours trying everything I could find online to fix this, but nothing I tried made a difference.  I finally upgraded to php7.4 and that fixed me.  I followed these instructions for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146109/how-to-update-upgrade-php-7-2-to-latest-php-7-3-safely except I exchanged 7.4 for 7.3 everywhere.